# How to Add a Variable for Solution Selection

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

I created a SourcePath variable to my VSTS variable. It is not letting me put that into the Workspace Mapping.

*As a stopgap before moving to Azure DevOps, I am wanting to make the build work on any given TFVC branch. There is virtual no documentation on the on-prem VSTS implementation that we have.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every version of on-prem TFS (up through TFS 2018) that I've worked with, you can't; you have to use explicit workspace mappings without variables in them.

It looks like it was changed in Azure DevOps at some point to work, but it doesn't show up on the feature timeline, so I couldn't say what version of on-prem TFS/Azure DevOps Server it's present in.

Comment: Yeah, that is a completely false statement. But thanks.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? I've never seen an on-prem version where that worked, although I just tested and it looks like they *did* add support for doing that in Azure DevOps at some point (which is great), so I learned something new today.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't saying your first statement was wrong. TFVC is not dead. Azure DevOps has always supported TFVC. I've been using it for years on visualstudio.com. I don't want to argue about that. 

We are moving to Azure DevOps but like every transition we have to move over in stages. I believe you that there is not a way to do this with those fields.  I'm wanting to have a movable build that can be applied to a transient branch to build and publish to a specific environment. Our Ops guy is already overloaded. Having to change the branch in 4 different places is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: I was saying it's dead from an "ongoing feature development" perspective. It's still supported and support isn't going anywhere, but Microsoft's focus clearly has been and will continue to be on Git as the preferred version control system.